# Copy the contents of a table in the body of an email from Outlook Inbox to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using **Outlook 2010** and **Excel 2010**. Daily I'm getting 200 emails with ***same subject*** and **tabular data** in the body (The table will be same all over the mails). I need to copy the **data in the table** to Excel in the same format as they are recieved. Kindly help me out in this..

Comment: This question is basically the opposite use-case of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670498/how-to-insert-a-table-after-body-of-e-mail-and-before-signature/56673269#56673269). You will not (obviously) need to create the OFT template file, but may use that framework to handle the `WordEditor` instance of the `MailItem` object, then you can handle the table(s) and copy/paste into Excel.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: The question is also too broad (you seem to be asking for a fully implemented solution, while contributing apparently zero effort of your own).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event to get notified when a new mail arrives. Then you can get an instance of the just arrived item using the EntryID value passed to the NewMailEx event handler. The [GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method of the Namespace class returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid).

Also you may consider handling the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class. It is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Be aware, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

You can read more about that in the series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

After getting an instance of the MailItem class which represents the incoming email you can get the required information parsing the message body. There are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. Word editor. The Inspector class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .