# How to insert a table after body of e-mail and before signature?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a below code that is pasting a table from excel to the outlook file. However, right now the table is pasted on the very bottom of the email - after the signature.

What I would like to achieve is to have the table inserted after a word "region." and before "Regards" - so before signature.

```
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DateString As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim myOutlook As Object
Dim myMailItem As Object
Dim mySubject As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim i As Integer
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'Prompt for Email Subject

Set outlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
weeknumber = "Week " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbMonday)
'mySubject = InputBox("Subject for Email")
For i = 2 To 3
region = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
mySubject = "Overdue Milestones | " & weeknumber & " | " & region

'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
'Create new folder to save the new files in
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = "C:\Users\mxr0520\Desktop\Ignite Reports\Milestones\" & weeknumber
If i < 3 Then
MkDir FolderName
Else
End If
'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
Set sh = Sheets(region)
    'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
    If sh.Visible = -1 Then
        sh.Copy
        'Set Destwb to the new workbook
        Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
        'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
        With Destwb
            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                'You use Excel 97-2003
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
            Else
                'You use Excel 2007-2016
                If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                    MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                    GoTo GoToNextSheet
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            End If
        End With
        'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
        If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
            With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Cells(1).Select
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        'Save the new workbook, email it, and close it
        'Set otlNewMail = outlApp.CreateItem(myMailItem)

        Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set OutlookMailitem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutlookMailitem
            .display
            End With
            Signature = OutlookMailitem.htmlbody

        With Destwb
            .SaveAs FolderName _
                  & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                    FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        End With
        myPath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        With Destwb
            .Close False
        End With

        With OutlookMailitem
            .Subject = mySubject
            .To = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
            .CC = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7)
            .htmlbody = "Dear All," & "<br>" _
            & "<br>" _
            & "Attached please find the list of milestones that are <b>overdue</b> and <b>due in 14 days</b> for " & region & "." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Regards," & "<br>" _
            & "Marek" _
            & Signature
            .Attachments.Add myPath

    Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:E14").Copy
    Set vInspector = OutlookMailitem.GetInspector
    Set weditor = vInspector.WordEditor

    wEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.body)
    wEditor.Application.Selection.End = wEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

            .display

        End With
        Set OutlookMailitem = Nothing
    End If
```

thank you for help in advance!

Comment: What does `Len(.body)` return? Shot in the dark, maybe try making that `Len(.body) - 1` or `Len(.body) - 2`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solutions below?

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions. I tried, but it gets blocked at a very beggining when declaring variables: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". For the first line ("Dim objOutlook as outlook.Application").

Comment: Ok got it - i had to adjust settings. all good - works fantastic. thank you David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to do this by creating an .oft (Outlook Email Template) with the message body and a placeholder for "region" and the table. Create the template without a signature, it will be added automatically per your Outlook user settings, later. I create a template like this, and save as .oft:

[image]

Then simply create the new mailitem with `Set OutlookMailitem = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate({path to your template.oft})`, replace the "region" placeholder, and copy/paste the table to the table placeholder's location.

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim tblRange As Word.Range
Dim region As String
' define your Region, probably this is done in a loop...
region = "Region 1"
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
' Create email from the template file // UPDATE WITH YOUR TEMPLATE PATH
Set objMsg = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\path\to\your\template.oft")
objMsg.Display
Set wdDoc = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
' replace placeholder with region:
wdDoc.Range.Find.Execute "{{REGION PLACEHOLDER}}", ReplaceWith:=region
' in my template, paragraph 5 is the table placeholder, modify as needed:
Set tblRange = wdDoc.Range.Paragraphs(5).Range
tblRange.Text = ""  ' remove the placeholder text
' copy the Excel table // modify to refer to your correct table/range
Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Range.Copy
' paste the table into the email
tblRange.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

End Sub
```

As you can see, the final email contains my default signature (which was **not** part of the template.oft file).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following properties to customize the message body:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. The Word Editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. You can find all these ways described in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for detecting signatures. You parse the message body and try to find such places.

However, when you create a signature in Outlook, three files (HTM, TXT and RTF) are created in the following folders:

**Vista and Windows 7/8/10**:

```
 C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

**Windows XP**:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

`Application Data` and `AppData` are hidden folders, change the view in the Windows explorer so it shows hidden files and folders if you want to see the files.

So, you read the content of these files and try to find the corresponding content in the message body. Note, users may type a custom signature in the end of emails.