# excel vba send email with embed image

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I used below macro to create email with embedded picture but it didn't work, as I kept on receiving

> run time error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument"

and highlighted this code `.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML`.

```
Sub Outlook_Email_With_Inline_Image()
    'Add reference to Microsoft Outlook Object Library
    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    'Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    'Dim oOutlookEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    'Create New Outlook Email Item to Attach Image(s)
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOutlookEmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Actual Excel VBA to send email with Embedded images
    With oOutlookEmail
        .To = "user@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Congrats"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Username\Pictures\Michael's Email Promotion\Angela.jpg", olByValue, 0
        sImgName = "ImageFile.img"
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:" & sImgName & "'" & " ><br>" 'Mention only the image file name not its path
        'Or Use this below line.
        '.HTMLBody = "<img src='" & sImgName & "'" & " ><br>"
        .Display
    '    .Send 'or just put .Display to check
    End With

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you can hack the `HTMLBody` this way, at the very least, I don't think it can be done quite so simply (but if it works based on other answers, below, keep using it). I would recommend creating an .oft Outlook Template and manipulating the email body from its `WordEditor`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670498/how-to-insert-a-table-after-body-of-e-mail-and-before-signature/56673269#56673269) is an example of placing a table inside an email body, which you could easily change to insert image instead of table.

Comment: I'm too new to vba and got excited when it worked, specially when you gave me the hint! Thank you so much for sharing this example, I love the learning experience that all members share here!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub email()

Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim obj As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim myDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim ToCc As Range, strBody, strSig As String
Dim fColorBlue, fColorGreen, fColorRed, fDukeBlue1, fDukeBlue2, fAggieMaroon, fAggieGray As String
Dim Greeting, emailContent As String
Dim emailOpen, emailSig As String



For Each ToCc In ActiveSheet.[A2:A2]


'=============================================================

Dim ToEmail, CcEmail, ToNm, CcNm As String
Dim DescrDt, DescrID, DescrNm As String

    ToNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [C1].Column).Value
    CcNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [G1].Column).Value
    ToEmail = Cells(ToCc.Row, [E1].Column).Value
    CcEmail = Cells(ToCc.Row, [I1].Column).Value

    DescrID = Cells(ToCc.Row, [B1].Column).Value
    DescrNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [D1].Column).Value
    DescrDt = "20190426"



'=============================================================
'''determine strBody --email message

Dim strFontSize, strFontName, strFontColor As String
    strFontName = "Arial"
    strFontColor = fAggieGray
    strFontSize = 13


Greeting = "<BODY style=" & Chr(34) & "font-family:" & strFontName & "; font-size:" & strFontSize & Chr(34) & ">" & _
            "<span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ToNm) & "," & "<br> <br>" & _
            "</span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & "</BODY>"



emailSig = "<BODY style=" & Chr(34) & "font-family:" & strFontName & "; font-size:" & strFontSize & Chr(34) & ">" & _
            "<span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & _
    "<br> <br>" & "- OE & HRIS Team" & "<br>" & "______________________" & "<br> <br>" & _
            "</span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & "</BODY>" & _
            "<BODY style=" & Chr(34) & "font-family:" & strFontName & "; font-size: 10px;"">" & _
            "<span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & _
    "[Email generated through Excel Macros and Google meme download - source data: October 3, 2019]" & _
            "</span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & "</BODY>"



Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
Set oAttach1 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\AA.jpg")
Set oAttach2 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\BB.png")
Set oAttach3 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\CC.jpg")
Set oAttach4 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\DD.gif")
Set oAttach5 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\EE.png")
Set oAttach6 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\FF.jpg")
Set oAttach7 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\GG.jpg")

Set olkPA1 = oAttach1.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA2 = oAttach2.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA3 = oAttach3.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA4 = oAttach4.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA5 = oAttach5.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA6 = oAttach6.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA7 = oAttach7.PropertyAccessor



olkPA1.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "AA.jpg"
olkPA2.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "BB.png"
olkPA3.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "CC.jpg"
olkPA4.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "DD.gif"
olkPA5.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "EE.png"
olkPA6.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "FF.jpg"
olkPA7.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "GG.jpg"


oEmail.Close olSave



oEmail.HTMLBody = Greeting & "<BODY style=" & Chr(34) & "font-family:" & strFontName & "; font-size:" & strFontSize & Chr(34) & ">" & _
            "<span style=""color:" & strFontColor & """>" & _
    "<br> <br>" & _
                    "<img src=""cid:FF.jpg""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "<br> <br>" & "<img src=""cid:AA.jpg""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "<br> <br>" & "<img src=""cid:BB.png""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "<br> <br>" & "<img src=""cid:DD.gif""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "<br> <br>" & "<img src=""cid:GG.jpg""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "<br> <br>" & "<img src=""cid:EE.png""height=520 width=750>" & _
                    "</body>"

oEmail.Save
oEmail.To = "MM@email.com"
oEmail.CC = "AA@email.com"

oEmail.Subject = "Congrats " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ToNm) & Chr(32) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(DescrNm)
oEmail.display
'oEmail.send



NEXT_ToCC:
    Set aEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
Next ToCc

'oEmail.Send

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using late-binding, then you can't use members of the Outlook [`OlBodyFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat) enum.

`olFormatHTML` corresponds to `2`.

```
Sub Outlook_Email_With_Inline_Image()
    Const olFormatHTML As Long = 2
    ...
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    ...
End Sub
```

Also - add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and declare *all* variables.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen, there's no error msg, however, I couldn't get the image, I got "x" object instead of the picture I'm trying to embed, can you check why?

Comment: I'm not strong in HTML but my guess is that `"ImageFile.img"` should be `"Angela.jpg"` (unfortunately cannot check atm).

Comment: Yes, you're right I changed the image file to the name of image and it worked perfectly great. However, what if I have multiple images, how can I embed them?

Comment: I'm not sure. You may get more help by asking that as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your help @BigBen! I found the right code for multiple images, I just need to declare the path of each image: 
Set oAttach1 = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\AA.jpg") and Set olkPA1 = oAttach1.PropertyAccessor then olkPA1.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "AA.jpg" and I was able to embed all images. Let me know if you need the full macro, I would be happy to help. By the way it's my first macro and I'm so happy

Comment: It's hard to read that code in a comment so you could add it as an answer to your own question :)